# GNOME Terminal Title as Number/Position of the tab

Tags: 12.04, command-line, gnome, bash, gnome-terminal

Searched and not found here. So posting it as fresh question.

**Usage:**
GNOME Terminal Version  3.4.1.1
Ubuntu 12.04

I used to open multiple tabs in GNOME Terminal. If the count is less then 4 or 5 I able to visually reorganize the total number and navigate into the particular tab using "**ALT + 3**".

When the total number of tabs is more then 6 or 7 or more, it's hard to find the number (nth) tab.

**Question:** Is there a way to rename or update the terminal title with the number (e.g. 1 for First tab, 2 for second tab and so on)? So that I can navigate between the tabs using "**ALT + Number**"